# What is live templating or templating in general? How is it different from a template one uses in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I'm reading an AngularJS book which states:

> In classic web frameworks, such as Rails, the controller combines data from models and mashes them
>   together with templates to deliver a view to the user. This combination produces a single-way view.
>   Without building any custom JavaScript components, the view will only reflect the data the model
>   exposes at the time of the view rendering. At the time of this writing, there are several JavaScript
>   frameworks that promise automatic data binding of the view and the model.
>
> AngularJS takes a different approach. Instead of merging data into a
>   template and replacing a DOM element, AngularJS creates live templates
>   as a view. Individual components of the views are dynamically
>   interpolated live. This feature is arguably one of the most important
>   in AngularJS and allows us to write the hello world app we just wrote
>   in only 10 lines of code without a single line of JavaScript

Not really sure what they mean by "AngularJS creates live templates as a view"

Answer (score 1):

roadtocode,

What I believe the book you are reading is trying to tell you is that, AngularJS doesn't inject your data inside your HTML, but instead, compile and recompile data-bindings, making it an "alive code". Rewording it, with other client-server types of communication, if the server changes, you need to load up the entire HTML with your data, even though most of the HTML was **reusable**. AngularJS will save you not only this processing but also the task of making the UI updated every time your data backing it changes too.

I would like to recommend you a very good reading on this topic: "AngularJS Up and Running" by Shyam Seshadri and Brad Green, pages 4 through 9.